# Running CloudNativePG primary node in same zone as synchronous replications

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, cloudnative-pg

I'm deploying CloudNativePG to bare metal. I have 3 zones where my k8s cluster is running across: `zone-1`, `zone-2`, `zone-3`

I wanna deploy PG cluster consisted of:

- 1 primary node (zone-1)
- 2 synchronous replication (zone-1)
- 1 asynchronous replication (zone-2)
- 1 asynchrnous replication (zone-3)

I assume the only way as of now is to configure it via `podAntiAffinity` but I cannot find really simple way to do that. Any help, please?

Comment: what if you lose zone-1?